# Delete in Wordpress Tables

Tags: mysql

I have these wordpress tables:

`jlc_posts` and `jlc_postmeta`

I did a query like this:

```
SELECT po.post_title,alm.meta_key,alm.meta_value,pmstock.meta_key,pmstock.meta_value
FROM jlc_posts po LEFT JOIN jlc_postmeta alm ON po.id = alm.post_id LEFT JOIN jlc_postmeta pmstock ON po.id = pmstock.post_id where alm.meta_key='almacen' and (alm.meta_value=1 or alm.meta_value=2) AND (pmstock.meta_key='_stock' and pmstock.meta_value=0)
```

And it works fine, but how can I convert this query to a DELETE query?
I can't find the answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE keyID = (SELECT po.post_title,alm.meta_key,alm.meta_value,pmstock.meta_key,pmstock.meta_value
FROM jlc_posts po LEFT JOIN jlc_postmeta alm ON po.id = alm.post_id LEFT JOIN jlc_postmeta pmstock ON po.id = pmstock.post_id where alm.meta_key='almacen' and (alm.meta_value=1 or alm.meta_value=2) AND (pmstock.meta_key='_stock' and pmstock.meta_value=0));
```